# Conjoining Where Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
UPDATE
    dbo.FormDetail
SET 
    FieldOrder=FieldOrder+1
WHERE
    WHERE DocCode IN (1,2,3)
    AND FieldOrder >= (SELECT FieldOrder FROM dbo.FormDetail
                       WHERE FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'
                       AND DocCode IN (1,2,3))
```

Don't know how clear it is what I'm trying to do here but I want to increase the `FieldOrder` in the `FormDetail` table for a number of documents but only after a certain field (basically so I have a gap to insert a new field). But the obvious problem is that the `FieldOrder` I get in my `Where` will not be specific to the document that the statement may currently be updating. I was thinking it's probably possible using partitions but I have only ever used `partitions` in `From` sections. Any help would be really appreciated.

**UPDATE**

dbo.FormDetail Sample Data

**DocCode     FieldOrder     FieldData**

1            1       'Title'

1            2       'OldField'

1            3       'Signature'

2            1       'Paragraph'

2            2       'OldField'

3            1       'OldField'

Comment: Some example data could clarify this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your existing code your sub-query is executed once and returns all it's results in one go to your outer query.

What you actually appear to want is for the sub-query to be executed once for every row being processed by the outer query.  The is called a *correlated* sub-query.

To make it work like that I have made two changes;
1.  I've given the table an alias in the sub-query
2.  I've changed the sub-query WHERE clause to reference the table in the outer-query

```
UPDATE
  dbo.FormDetail
SET
  FieldOrder=FieldOrder+1
WHERE
  DocCode IN (1,2,3)
  AND FieldOrder >= (SELECT lookup.FieldOrder
                       FROM dbo.FormDetail AS lookup
                      WHERE lookup.FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'
                        AND lookup.DocCode = FormDetail.DocCode
                    )
```

Another alternative could be to join on a sub-query...

```
UPDATE
  FormDetail
SET
  FieldOrder=FieldOrder+1
FROM
  dbo.FormDetail
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    DocCode,
    FieldOrder
  FROM
    dbo.FormDetail
  WHERE
    DocCode IN (1,2,3)
    AND FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'
)
  AS lookup
    ON  lookup.DocCode     = FormDetail.DocCode
    AND lookup.FieldOrder >= FormDetail.FieldOrder
```

Comment: Hmm so because you changed the inner `FormDetail` to `Lookup`, `FormDetail.DocCode` is now referencing the `DocCode` in the outer statement? Am I understanding that right?

Comment: @killianmcc - I've editted to explicity state `lookup.` in the correlated sub-query. Due to scope rules they're no strictly necessary, but being explicit is never a bad idea :)  It also shows that `FormDetail.DocCode` can't possibly be referrencing `lookup`, and so it *must* be referencing the outer query's instance of `FormDetail`.

Comment: Your first code example doesn't work. You're doing a greater-than comparison on a result set. I can't see how that executes without an error.

Comment: @MelPadden - It's a correlated sub-query; it is essential executed for each and every row processed in the outer query. This means that the inner WHERE clause would be `WHERE DocCode = 1 AND FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'` in some rows, and `WHERE DocCode = 2 AND FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'` in other rows, etc, etc. For the example data these `WHERE` clauses will always yield one and only one record. If they yield more than one record, then the OP needs to change the logic to ensure the correlated sub-query identifies a single record per `DocCode`. *(But, at present, it's fine.)*

Comment: @Dems Well actually I did want it to move more than one record (every record after `'%OldField%'`) which this does. I just didn't bother to include that much example data.

Comment: @killianmcc - The `one and only one record` statement, in my comment to MelPadden, is in reference to the `FieldOrder >= (subquery)`. The sub-query must only return one value; you can't have `FieldOrder >= (2,2,1)`. As you have `>=`, however, multiple records in the outer query satisfy that condition, even though the sub-query only returns a single value.  The use of the correlated sub-query just means that the single value returned can be a different value each time it's called; a different value for each row in the outer query, but always only one value at a time.

Answer (score 0):

What error are you getting? The only thing I can see wrong is that you're not limiting your subquery. On a large dataset it might be a bit inefficient, but for the moment all you need is a MIN();

```
DECLARE @FormDetail TABLE(
    DocCode         INT
,   Fieldorder      INT
,   FieldData       NVARCHAR(MAX)
)

INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (1,1, 'Title')
INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (1,2, 'OldField')
INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (1,3, 'Signature')
INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (2,1, 'Paragraph')
INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (2,2, 'OldField')
INSERT INTO @FormDetail (DocCode, FieldOrder, FieldData) VALUES (3,1, 'OldField')


UPDATE @FormDetail SET      
    FieldOrder = FieldOrder + 1 
WHERE 
    DocCode IN (1,2,3)     
AND FieldOrder >= (
    SELECT MIN(FieldOrder) FROM @FormDetail                        
    WHERE FieldData LIKE '%OldField%'                        
    AND DocCode IN (1,2,3)
) 

SELECT * FROM @FormDetail
```

Gives the following:

1   2   Title

1   3   OldField

1   4   Signature

2   2   Paragraph

2   3   OldField

3   2   OldField

All you want is to increment your fieldorder after a certain point, right?

Comment: You've made a false assumption. You don't want `MIN(FieldOrder)` *(To allow this to stand on it's own as a scalar function)* you actually want a different value of `FieldOrder` for each `DocCode` *(a correlated sub-query, when using this structure)*.  *[Records that should have FieldOrder incremented are (1,2) (1,3) (2,2) and (3,1).]*

Comment: Only FieldOrders >= '%OldField%' should be incremented.

Comment: Just getting back to this now - yep I see that. Kudos. I did indeed make a false assumption, or rather made the fatal error of not understanding the data enough but looking at the code.